# Why does Python's "for" iterate the length of the list even if I change the length in the loop?

Tags: python

I came across this question using python.

```
l = [1,2,3,4]

for i in l:
    x = l.pop(0)
    print(x)
    l.insert(0,x)
```

And the result gives me `1,1,1,1`. I was wondering why this could happen? Shouldn't I have infinite 1's?

Comment: Modifying a list while you're iterating over it is generally a recipe for weird unintended things happening.

Comment: This is a good question, but the title is too simple. You could maybe change it to something like, *'Why does Python's "for" iterate the length of the list even if I change the length in the loop?'* For tips on writing a good title, see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: If it'd help your understanding, check out this MCoding video: [For loops are redundant](https://youtu.be/Xd760PcgfPg). It's about using `while True` to emulate `for`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a point worth to pay attention to. when your for loop start it  navigate through your list, starting from the first item which is "1" in your list. it pop  ( remove the item) and print the removed item! after this stage you have  2 ,3 ,4 in your list. and finally you add the item you have removed back to your list. when the loop execute again it does exactly what did before. in fact your "i" variable in the loop has finite values (1,2,3,4) and the code inside the loop repeat only 4 times!.
I hope you get the point but if not let's trace your code as below

```
i=1   x=1  print(1) l = [1,2,3,4]
i=2   x=1  print(1) l = [1,2,3,4]
i=3   x=1  print(1) l = [1,2,3,4]
i=4   x=1  print(1) l = [1,2,3,4]
```

add print(l) at the end of your code to see what exactly happens to your list for each "i" in your for loop.

Comment: OP did not expect to have 1,2,3,4 - they expected to have infinite 1s.